# X-Printer P323B print nothing

Tags: javascript, oracle-jet, xprinter

I have a x-printer P323B, I made an oraclejet app and try to print a arbitary text the paper is ejected but print nothing ,there is an assumption that this issue is due to unicode this is what I was try :

```
    self.buttonClick = function () {
      var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;
      // permissions.requestPermission(permissions.BLUETOOTH, success, error);
      permissions.requestPermission(
        permissions.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
        success,
        error,
      );

      function error() {
        console.warn("Camera permission is not turned on");
      }

      function success(status) {
        if (!status.hasPermission) error();

        BTPrinter.list(
          function (data) {
            console.log("Success");
            console.log(data); // paired bluetooth devices array
          },
          function (err) {
            console.log("Error");
            console.log(err);
          },
        );
        BTPrinter.connect(
          function (data) {
            console.log("Success connect");
            console.log(data);

            BTPrinter.printText(
              function (data) {
                console.log("Success print");
                console.log(data);
              },
              function (err) {
                console.log("Error print");
                console.log(err);
              },
              "m Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum",
            );
          },

          function (err) {
            console.log("Error connect");
            console.log(err);
          },
          "XP-P323B-57B1",
        );
      }
    };
```

I saw many videos on how to setup the x-printer correctly but with no success